# libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 6895 (WebViewCoreThre)

Tags: android, iphone, appcelerator-studio

I am getting the following error:

```
[INFO] :   libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 6895 (WebViewCoreThre)
```

After sending to webView over 700 items on emulator and 200 to device, the program crashes and restarts automatically. I have spent many days trying to solve this without success.

What could be causing this?

If necessary I can send a complete project. Ask it at my email nilmarpublio@gmail.com

My code is:

```
var count = 0;
//
// create base UI tab and root window
//
    var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'BtTest',
    backgroundColor:'#eff2d8',
    layout: 'vertical'
});

var mainView = Ti.UI.createView({
     top: 0,
     width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
     height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
     backgroundColor: '#7cd0F7',

});

var webView = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    top:10, 
    left: 20,
    height: 250, 
    width: 250,
    cacheMode: Ti.UI.Android.WEBVIEW_LOAD_NO_CACHE,
    borderColor: 'black',
    url: 'html/stress.html'
});
mainView.add(webView);

    var webView1 = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    top:250, 
    left: 0,
    height: 250, 
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    cacheMode: Ti.UI.Android.WEBVIEW_LOAD_NO_CACHE,
    borderColor: 'black',
    url: 'html/stressChart.html'
}); 
mainView.add(webView1);

var xtm0 = 0;

function send(valor)
{
    xtm0 = setInterval(function()
    {       
        console.log(count++);
        var valor = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);  
        Ti.App.fireEvent("app:fromGauge", {message: valor});
        Ti.App.fireEvent("app:fromChart", {message: valor});
    }, 500);
}

send();

win.add(mainView);
win.open();
```

HTML files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Gauge Test</title>
    <script src="../js/gauge.js"></script>
    <style>body
           {
               padding:0;
               margin:0;
               background:#a3a3a3
           }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload = "showGauge()">
    <canvas id="gauge">
    </canvas>
    <div id="console">
    </div>
<script>
function showGauge() 
{
    var gauge = new Gauge(
    {
        renderTo    : 'gauge',
        width       : 250,
        height      : 250,
        glow        : true,
        units       : '%',
        title       : false,
        minValue    : 0,
        maxValue    : 100,
        majorTicks  : ['0', '20', '40', '60', '80','100'],
        minorTicks  : 20,
        strokeTicks : false,
        highlights  : [
            { from :   0,   to :   20, color : 'rgba( 255, 255,  255, 1)' },
            { from :  20,   to :   40, color : 'rgba(   0, 201, 255, 1)' },
            { from :  40,   to :   80, color : 'rgba( 255,   0, 130, 1)' },
            { from :  80,   to :  100, color : 'rgba( 255,   0,   0, 1)' } 
        ],
        colors: {
            plate      : '#222',
            majorTicks : '#f5f5f5',
            minorTicks : '#ddd',
            title      : '#fff',
            units      : '#fff',
            numbers    : '#eee',
            needle     : { start : 'rgba(255, 32, 12, 1)', end : 'rgba(255, 167, 12, 1)' }
        }
    });

    gauge.onready = function()
    {
        Ti.App.addEventListener("app:fromGauge", function(e) 
        {   
            var msg = e.message;
            gauge.setValue(msg);
        });
    };
    gauge.draw();

    // inibe as barras de scroll
    document.ontouchmove = function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    };
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Flot Examples: Real-time updates</title>
    <link href="../flot/examples/examples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../flot/examples/jquery.js"></script>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../flot/examples/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../flot/examples/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../flot/examples/jshashtable-2.1.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../flot/examples/jquery.numberformatter-1.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../flot/examples/jquery.flot.symbol.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../flot/examples/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
    <script>

var data = [];
var dataset;
var totalPoints = 100;
var updateInterval = 1000;
var now = new Date().getTime();

function GetData() {
    data.shift();

    while (data.length < totalPoints) {     
        var y = Math.random() * 100;
        var temp = [now += updateInterval, y];
        data.push(temp);
    }
}

var options = {
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true,
            lineWidth: 1,
            fill: false
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
       font:
       {
            size: 10,
            style: "normal",
            family: "sans-serif",
            color: "black"
        },
        mode: "time",
        tickSize: [2, "second"],
        tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
           var date = new Date(v);

            if (date.getSeconds() % 20 == 0) {
                var hours = date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() : date.getHours();
                var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
                var seconds = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();

                return (hours + ':' + minutes);
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        },
//        axisLabel: "Time",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 8,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana',
        axisLabelPadding: 10
    },
    yaxis: {
           font:
           {
                size: 10,
                style: "normal",
                family: "sans-serif",
                color: "black"
            },
        min: 0,
        max: 100,        
        tickSize: 5,
        tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
            if (v % 10 == 0) {
                return v;
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        },
//        axisLabel: "CPU loading",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana',
        axisLabelPadding: 6
    },
    legend: {        
        labelBoxBorderColor: "#fff"
    },
    grid: {                
        backgroundColor: "#000000",
        tickColor: "#008040"
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
//    GetData();

    dataset = [
        { data: data, color: "#00FF00" }
    ];

    $.plot($("#flot-placeholder1"), dataset, options);

    function update() {

        $.plot($("#flot-placeholder1"), dataset, options);
    }

    Ti.App.addEventListener("app:fromChart", function(e) 
    {            
        var msg = e.message;
        GetData(msg);
        update();
    });

    document.ontouchmove = function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    };
});

</script>
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="flot-placeholder1" style="width:200px; height:330px"> </div>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that your question should be readable on its own.

Comment: If you want to post full code, you could use a site like [http://0bin.net/](http://0bin.net/) and post a link to your code.